# How to abort ALL remaining functions if condition is false/null

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've got a couple of ajax scripts running in my file to check if a users exists and then to create a user. The goal is simply to check if the user exists from the first ajax call and then the second call is to create the user if they do not exist.

This ajax.done function for userCheck_settings condition returns properly and checks if the response has a value of null, if it does, it returns false. However, the following createUser function still runs. Is it possible to abort **ALL** of the remaining functions?

```
function checkUser(responseToken) {

        $('.btn').click(function () {

            const Url = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://staging.micromerchantsystems.com/mmsgatewayapistaging/api/patient/search';

            var user_firstName = $("#first_name").val();
            var user_lastName = $("#last_name").val();
            var user_dob = $('#date_of_birth').val();

            const userCheck = {
                "RequestingClient": {
                    "ClientId": "***********",
                    "MemberId": "***********"
                },
                "Pharmacy": {
                    "IdentifierType": 2,
                    "Identifier": "5164086800"
                },
                "LastName": user_lastName,
                "FirstName": user_firstName,
                "DOB": "04/27/1901",
                "MobileNumber": "123456789",
            };

            var userCheck_string = JSON.stringify(userCheck);

            var userCheck_settings = {
                "async": true,
                "crossDomain": true,
                "url": Url,
                "method": "POST",
                "headers": {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    "Authorization": "Bearer " + responseToken,
                    "Accept": "*/*",
                },
                "data": userCheck_string
            }

            $.ajax(userCheck_settings).done(function (response) {

                if (response.Patients == null) {
                    console.log('Reponse is null! ' + response.Patients);
                    return false;
                    console.log('This does not show');
                } else {
                    console.log('Response is NOT null! Last Name is: ' + response.Patients[0].LastName);
                }

            });
        });
    }



function createUser(responseToken) {
        $('.btn').click(function () {
          console.log('I dont want this to run');
        });
    }
```

Comment: where are you calling these functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When both of your functions (checkUser and createUser) are called, the same click event listener on the elements that have the .btn css class is added:

```
$('.btn').click(function () {
     //...
}
```

I'm assuming you have that css class on a button but regardless, when you click that, both code blocks inside each click event handlers are executed virtually simultaneously. In other words, the functions checkUser and createUser themselves are NOT being called directly but rather the code inside the event handlers. If you only want to createUser when no user exists I would suggest calling the createUser function from inside the logic that tells you that the user does not exist something like this:

```
// truncated for brevity .......
 $.ajax(userCheck_settings).done(function (response) {

            if (response.Patients == null) {
               //create user function call from here
               //I'm not sure what the responseToken parameter should be but this is just an example
                createUser(responseToken);
                return false;
                console.log('This does not show');
            } else {
                console.log('Response is NOT null! Last Name is: ' + response.Patients[0].LastName);
            }

        });
  //truncated for brevity .......

 //then the createUser function
 function createUser(responseToken) {
   //removed click event listener
   //write your code to create user here
}
```

Note that click event handler should be removed from the createUser function.